# Simple ReWriteRule expanded with an anchor

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi from Central Australia, Thankyou for your help

I have a simple re-write like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule Trades-Services-(.*) Trades-Services.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

what this does is turns the URL like this

```
http://website.com/Trades-Services-Plumber
```

into this

```
http://website.com/Trades-Services.php?cat=Plumber
```

what I hope for is to further (or compliment) that rewrite rule so it will turn this

```
http://website.com/Trades-Services-Plumber-123
```

into this

```
http://website.com/Trades-Services.php?cat=Plumber&ad=123#123
```

- Where it throws on an anchor as well (#123)
- the 123 could be any number and is always the same as the anchor
- while still preserving that first functionality
- it could also work with a URL like Civil-Celebrant instead of Plumber

e.g

```
http://website.com/Trades-Services-Civil-Celebrant-123
to
http://website.com/Trades-Services.php?cat=Civil-Celebrant&ad=123#123
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

To do the bulk of the rewrite, you'd need to change your existing rules and add the extra one to handle the second case:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Trades-Services-(.+)-([0-9]+)$ /Trades-Services.php?cat=$1&ad=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Trades-Services-(.+)$ /Trades-Services.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

This should cover 3 of your 4 requirements, except for the first:

> Where it throws on an anchor as well (#123)

The URL fragment, the **#123** bit, is handled by the browser and when urls have a #name in it, the #name fragment is never sent to the server. So there's no way the server knows about the fragment, it's something the browser sees and the browser seeks to the anchor in the document. Something you could do is *redirect* to get the anchor. The first rule would then look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^Trades-Services-(.+)-([0-9]+)$ /Trades-Services.php?cat=$1&ad=$2#$2 [L,NC,R]
```

However, when someone enters **http://website.com/Trades-Services-Plumber-123** in their browser's address bar, that rule will REDIRECT the browser to **http://website.com/Trades-Services.php?cat=Plumber&ad=123#123**, thus what's in their browser's address bar changes to the php URI. This isn't the same behavior you have in your original rule (which redirects internally on the server-side, preserving what's in the browser's address bar). The other thing you can do is when you generate links like **http://website.com/Trades-Services-Plumber-123**, ensure that there's a fragment added to it: **http://website.com/Trades-Services-Plumber-123#123**.